# Performance on Google Maps and SqlLite

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, google-maps

In my application I have a Activity with google map and a GPS to get my location as I am walking.
The application works well, as I'm walking the map will show what is close to min (markers)
my problem:
Knowing that SqlLite is not supported math functions for distance calculation points, must seek all entry and make the calculation by a method in my code, keeping in memory, however, lose performance to get all the bank's record and analyze each.
Any suggestions of what I can do to improve application performance, considering a bank with 60,000 coordinate registration

Comment: You have to do the computations on a `AsyncTask` and save the result to the db together with your coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, SQLite does not provide GIS functions, but SpatiaLite does and there is a SpatiaLite port that works on Android.

I think the best solution is to store your coordinates in a SpatiaLite table (Geometric type will be POINT) and query your database using spatial functions (`ST_Distance` in your case):

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(4 1)', 4326), Geometry) < 10;
```

I have used SpatiaLite on Android on several projects and I can say that the performance is great.

Comment: Thank you Antonio, I will study this tool, I believe that is the way

Comment: @Pedro Otavio Gonçales Maitan you are welcome. Good luck with your project!